# Scala filter by set

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, set

Say I have a map that looks like this

```
val map = Map("Shoes" -> 1, "heels" -> 2, "sneakers" -> 3, "dress" -> 4, "jeans" -> 5, "boyfriend jeans" -> 6)
```

And also I have a set or collection that looks like this:

```
val set = Array(Array("Shoes", "heels", "sneakers"), Array("dress", "maxi dress"), Array("jeans", "boyfriend jeans", "destroyed jeans"))
```

I would like to perform a filter operation on my map so that only one element in each of my set retains. Expected output should be something like this:

```
map = Map("Shoes" -> 1, "dress" -> 4 ,"jeans" -> 5)
```

The purpose of doing this is so that if I have multiple sets that indicate different categories of outfits, my output map doesn't "repeat" itself on technically the same objects.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How do you pick which set element or map key wins over the others when they both overlap?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Could just pick the first element in the set.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your examples just a little - can't quite grasp what you are trying to do... tks

Comment: @ShirleyDu There's no such thing as "the first element". Sets and maps are  unordered. You could pick a random one, but then what is the point of this code?

Comment: @wwkudu Example added. In Python I could just do like as soon as I find one element, remove all others in the same set from my input list. However, I don't think I can apply the same logic to this map reduce job.

Comment: @Daenyth Picking a random one works, or I could just change the set to an array. The point of this code is to have only one element from each of the sets/arrays in my output.

Comment: Please take a look at the below answers and if one of them worked for you, consider marking it as accepted (by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer). This will indicate that the question no longer needs an answer, and it will also give reputation to the answerer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first get rid of the confusion that your sets are actually arrays. For the rest of the example I will use this definition instead:

```
val arrays = Array(Array("Shoes", "heels", "sneakers"), Array("dress", "maxi dress"), Array("jeans", "boyfriend jeans", "destroyed jeans"))
```

So in a sense you have an array of arrays of equivalent objects and want to remove all but one of them?

Well first you have to find which of the elements in an array are actually used as keys in the mep. So we just filter out all elements that are not used as keys:

```
array.filter(map.keySet)
```

Now, we have to chose one element. As you said, we just take the first one:

```
array.filter(map.keySet).head
```

As your "sets" are actually arrays, this is really the first element in your array that is also used as a key. If you would actually use sets this code would still work as sets actually have a "first element". It is just highly implementations specific and it might not even be deterministic over various executions of the same program. At least for immutable sets it should however be deterministic over several calls to head, i.e., you should always get the same element.

Instead of the first element we are actually interested in all other elements, as we want to remove them from the map:

```
array.filter(map.keySet).tail
```

Now, we just have to remove those from the map:

```
map -- array.filter(map.keySet).tail
```

And to do it for all arrays:

```
map -- arrays.flatMap(_.filter(map.keySet).tail)
```

This works fine as long as the arrays are disjoined. If they are not, we can not take the initial map to filter the array in every step. Instead, we have to use one array to compute a new map, then take the next starting with the result from the last and so on. Luckily, we do not have to do much:

```
arrays.foldLeft(map){(m,a) => m -- a.filter(m.keySet).tail}
```

Note: Sets are also functions from elements to Boolean, this is, why this solution works.

Comment: Elegant!  This is the better way to solve this particular problem, though I'll leave  my answer up as it's more widely applicable to related problems.

Comment: Or `map.filterKeys` taking the ones which are head of their group.

Comment: I had three reasons not to choose map.filterKeys, first of all, the sets in the questions are actually arrays, filtering something with respect to an array would be slow. Then I would loose the order of the array because the result of filterKeys would have the order of the map. Keeping the order allows me to actually choose a well defined first element. And finally I assumed the set to be small but the map to be possibly large and filterKeys is a linear operation. This way, the transformation is linear in the size of the set and effectively independent of the size of the map.

Comment: You do need to use `set.flatMap(_.filter(map.keySet).tail).toSet` to get it to actually work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you getting at? The original question was for one set/list. If you want to do this for multiple sets/lists as the questions asks now you have to do it multiple times of course, i.e. `map -- set.flatMap(_.filter(m.keySet).tail)`. You do not need the extra toSet though, -- removes any collection of keys.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to use `groupBy`.  Something  like

```
map.groupBy{ case (k,v) => g(k) }.
  map{ case (_, kvs) => kvs.head }
```

This is the general way to group similar things (using some function `g`).  Now the question is just how to make the `g` that you need.  One way is

```
val g = set.zipWithIndex.
  flatMap{ case (a, i) => a.map(x => x -> i) }.
  toMap
```

which labels each set with a number, and then forms a map so you can look it up.  Maps have an apply function, so you can use it as above.

Comment: I concur with your choice of groupBy, and your example is *so* much more concise than the convoluted answer I had been writing.

Comment: I don't really get this answer. First, there is some kind of mistake in the definition of `g`: `a` is a element of the set (i.e. a string) and your are mapping over it. As you are mapping over it, your are building a map from characters to indices. Also in the first part `kvs.head` is already a tuple, why are you taking it appart and putting it back together?

Comment: @dth - I fixed the tuple construction/deconstruction thing, thanks!  (Forgot to read what I ended up with after edits.)  But I think the name of the variable `set` is misleading you--what type is it actually in the original question?

Comment: A ok, well this is what happens, when questions change over time... I was writing the answer when it was still a single set/array. I'll clean it up later

Comment: OK, now I do get your solution, it however assumes, that that every element is actually contained in one of these arrays, and it also assumes, that these arrays are disjoined. From the new example I now can see, how you've arrived at your solution, because the example now actually has this partition structure.

Comment: @dth - We're all assuming that the arrays are disjoint, right?  Try yours on `Array(Array("jeans", "dress"), Array("dress", "jeans"))` for instance!  (Granted--I did suggest that correction, but the trivial alternative (folding the map) is O(n^2).)

Comment: I am not sure that the trivial alternative I had in mind is trivial or that it is the most obvious.

Comment: @Rex Well, my operation on a single array assumes nothing because I didn't know anything when I came up with it ;-) So it is pretty easy to use it, to handle the case, where the arrays are not disjoined. The only problem is, that the flatMap uses the same map in each step and not the intermediate results. A fold over the array solves that nicely. I hope the OP is actually interested in all this discussion and the different solutions. But then, it was fun anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This code solves the problem:

```
var newMap = map

set.foreach { list =>
  var remove = false
  list.foreach { _key =>
    if (remove) {
      newMap -= _key
    }
    if (newMap.contains(_key)) {
      remove = true
    }

  }
}
```

> I'm completely new at Scala. I have taken this as my first Scala
>   example, please any hints from Scala's Gurus is welcome.

Comment: Well, this is basically the imperative way to do it. If you program like this you might even consider using a mutable map as it might be fast. (Not in this case, because you touch only a few elements, so conversion to and from a mutable map would be much more expensive)

Comment: The problem is, it is more complicated, than the functional version. Here you have to grasp what the algorithm is doing, whereas the functional version can be understood step by step.

Comment: First, thanks for the insight, second I like the way you solve it and I'm pretty sure I would do it the same way if I where to know those features by now. Looking forward into learn a bit more about Scala.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler version

```
set.flatMap(_.find(map.contains).map(y => y -> map(y)))
```